# Cant read file within source code

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jenkins

Need some help with a problem. In one of my java classes, I need to access a file. The file has to be in the same location (in source code) as the java class in question. Here is the excerpt from the code.

```
String fileName = "myfile.myext"    
resource = "./" + fileName
String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(clazz.getResourceAsStream(resource));
```

And this works alright in my dev box in Eclipse. However, the moment I put it up on Jenkins (which is my CI server) it does not work. I have checked the following

1. The file "myfile.myext" exists in the jar that was deployed on
   Jenkins.
2. The Jenkins code not only does not find "myfile.myext" but
       it does not find "someOther.class" if I try to read the content of
       the class that way. Here "someOther.class" is an actual class that
       is a piece of the code.

A couple of things that might be relevant

1. The stuff that gets deployed in Jenkins is "myProduct.jar" and "myProduct_test.jar". My Junits are only in "myProduct_test.jar" and not in "myProduct.jar". Conversly all my product code lies only in "myProduct.jar" and the "myProduct_test.jar" simply uses that jar from classpath.

Net net, in Jenkins I cant get testcases to read the file from code base. In Eclipse I can.

Anybody has faced / solved this before?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you run your program in Eclipse, the code is run from the directory containing the code, whereas Jenkins runs it from some other directory. Thus, `./` does not refer to the directory containing the code.

You can use the `getResourceAsStream` method to load resources from locations in your classpath, and apparently deals with JAR bundling too. This [article on resource loading](http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading) should explain things somewhat.

However, this method should only really be used for files that the user never needs to interact with. If you want to store a user-edited configuration file, for example, it should be put somewhere else, such as an [Application Data directory](http://www.asjava.com/core-java/how-to-get-user-application-data-directory-in-java/).